# Search a value inside a json response from elasticsearch with python

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I need to get the value of a key inside a json response from ElasticSearch, but below code it's no finding nothing:

```
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    pattern = '"taskDefinitionId": "(.+?)"'
    result = re.findall(pattern, str(hit["_source"]))
    if result:
        print(result)
```

This is the key:value that I'm looking for:
 "taskDefinitionId": "PEOPLE_ARE_PLAYING",

I need to get "PEOPLE_ARE_PLAYING" inside result

Below is the entire json:

```
{
  "id": "tenant1#2019-06-03T19:03:50.024Z#68wer1-1rer79a-4fr5d-be9-db42cbe",
  "assignedToUser": "user",
  "attachments": [],
  "comments": [],
  "currentStatus": "COMPLETED",
  "slaExpiresAt": "2020-06-02T19:03:50.024Z",
  "history": [
    {
      "newStatus": "CLAIMED",
      "startedAt": "2019-06-03T19:03:50.024Z",
      "event": "TASK_CLAIMED"
    },
    {
      "currentStatus": "READY_TO_COMPLETE",
      "startedAt": "2019-06-03T19:09:51.072Z",
      "diff": [
        {
          "op": "add",
          "path": "/path",
          "value": {
            "address": "av dfasdfsadfhaskd",
            "name": "asd",
            "id": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "assignedByUser": "user",
      "event": "TASK_READY_TO_COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "currentStatus": "COMPLETED",
      "startedAt": "2019-06-03T19:09:51.272Z",
      "assignedByUser": "asfdasdfsd",
      "event": "TASK_COMPLETED"
    }
  ],
  "assignedToGroup": "asdfsdf",
  "circuitId": "6sdf24d1-1s9sa-4f5s-b969-db4sadfc12",
  "taskDefinitionId": "PEOPLE_ARE_PLAYING",
  "finishedAt": "2019-06-03T19:09:51.272Z",
  "createdAt": "2019-06-03T19:03:50.024Z",
  "taskType": "Automatic",
  "taskDefinitionName": "Definition",
  "payload": {
    "datos": {
      "address": "sdfasdfasdfsadfsd",
      "name": "asd",
      "id": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to your script, the only problem I can see is if does `hit["_source"]` hold the json string your claiming, I tried the regex and it should be working

Comment: for me it's not working and I don't know why but I found a better solution. I'm going to share it below.

Answer (score 0):

If `taskDefinitionId` is the `only` thing you want, then you can use [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering):

```
GET <your_index>/_search?filter_path=**.taskDefinitionId
```

If you need multiple fields, you can do

```
GET <your_index>/_search?filter_path=**.taskDefinitionId,**.currentStatus
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep but I need all the data. I'm looking for the taskDefinitionId to take a decision of where I have to store the json.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a realize that I'm getting a dict so...

```
mydict = hit["_source"]
print(mydict["taskDefinitionId"])
```